# Grep doesn't work when adding an extra character at the end of operator

Tags: ubuntu, grep

I am grepping (Ubuntu) multiples files with this command:

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8 grep  -P -R -i -I -H -A1 "^name#.*?r[AÀÁÂÃÄaàáâãä]f[AÀÁÂÃÄaàáâãä][EÈÉÊËeèéêë]l s[IÌÍÎÏiìíîï]m[OÔÒÓÕÖoòóôõö].*?#.*?#.*?#.*?#.*?\$" image_args_*
```

Which returns a few results, this being of them:

```
image_args_search_134.txt:name#Rafael Simões Vieira#1767###Emerenciana Rodrigues de Oliveira
image_args_search_134.txt-#bati.#134#somelinkhere.com##
--
```

but if I add [EÈÉÊËeèéêë] as part of the operator like shown below:

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8 grep  -P -R -i -I -H -A1 "^name#.*?r[AÀÁÂÃÄaàáâãä]f[AÀÁÂÃÄaàáâãä][EÈÉÊËeèéêë]l s[IÌÍÎÏiìíîï]m[OÔÒÓÕÖoòóôõö][EÈÉÊËeèéêë].*?#.*?#.*?#.*?#.*?\$" image_args_*
```

Then I get nothing.

Why is that?
Thanks!

Comment: I suggest to switch to single quotes, if possible.

Comment: If I replace double quotes with single quotes, then it doesn't work in both cases.

Comment: Is the `$` in your regexp supposed to be literal or the end-of-string regexp metachar? If the latter, remove the ```\``` from in front of it.

Comment: It is supposed to mean end-of-string.  I removed the \ and still doesn't work. This same command works on my iPage website. I am migrating it to Google Cloud Compute and that's where I am seeing this problem.

Comment: If you echo this to a file: name#Rafael Simões Vieira#1763### and then try to grep it, it doesn't work.

Comment: Probably a locale thing. It does not work with LC_ALL=C for me, but it does with LC_ALL=C.UTF-8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see your problem only, if i use some not installed locales.

Please verify that the required locales are activated (not commended out by leading `#`)

```
grep "en_US" /etc/locales.gen

# en_US ISO-8859-1
# en_US.ISO-8859-15 ISO-8859-15
en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8
```

(The file `/etc/locales.gen` can be configured to your needs by removing the commenting `#`)

Assure that these configured locales are really generated:

```
sudo update-locale
```

Comment: I can't find the file "/etc/locales.gen". How do I generate this file? I issued the command "sudo apt install locales-all" and it is working now. I feel that I have more locales than I need so I would like to remove all the unnecessary ones except en_US.UTF-8. How do I do that? When I issue the command "localectl list-locales", I see a long list of locales which I don't need.

Comment: I had to create the /etc/locales.gen file by issuing the command "sudo apt-get install locales". Then I edited the file "/etc/locales.gen" as you instructed. Now it is working.

Answer (score 1):

From what I notice, it looks like you would like to use all possible diacritics that fit a given letter. Within the concept of regular expressions, you can use *equivalence classes*.

> An equivalence class expression shall represent the set of collating elements belonging to an equivalence class, as described in Collation Order. Only primary equivalence classes shall be recognized. The class shall be expressed by enclosing any one of the collating elements in the equivalence class within bracket-equal ( `[=` and `=]` ) delimiters. For example, if 'a', 'à', and 'â' belong to the same equivalence class, then `[[=a=]b]`, `[[=à=]b]`, and `[[=â=]b]` are each equivalent to `[aàâb]`. If the collating element does not belong to an equivalence class, the equivalence class expression shall be treated as a collating symbol.

So you might want to write something based on:

```
$ grep -i 'r[[=a=]]f[[=a=]][[=e=]]l s[[=i=]]m[[=o=]][[=e=]]s' file1 file2 file3
```

Note that this does not exist in PCRE, so you just need to use extended regular expressions:

```
$ grep -A1 -iIREH '^name#[^#]*r[[=a=]]f[[=a=]][[=e=]]l s[[=i=]]m[[=o=]][[=e=]]s[^#]*(#[^#]*){4}$' *
```